# Changing contours from 5 ft to 10 ft in attribute table using QGIS

Tags: qgis, contour

I downloaded a file of contour lines that has a line every 5 ft of elevation change. This data is extremely dense and makes the map hard to read. Because I don't have the DEM or source data I can't create a new contours layer.

Is there a way to remove the unwanted data within the attribute table?

Ideally I'd like to have contours every 10 ft.

Comment: What have you tried? It seems like a modulus operator would make quick work of the selection.

Answer (score 5):

Set a definition query / provider feature filter using the "%" modulus operator to show only contours with an elevation value divisible evenly by 10:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Apart from filtering in `Layer Properties > Provider Feature Filer` ([answer by @user2856](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/438787/88814)), you can also select the features you want to keep by using `Select by expression` with the same expression:  `"elevation" % 10 = 0`

Copy / paste the selected features to a new layer (if you want to keep the other contours) or delete the contours you don't need: click `Invert Feature Selection` or directly select them with `"elevation" % 10 <> 0`

*Contours selected by the expression in yellow:*

[image]

If you just want to hide some of the contours, also think about rule based style: create a rule for `"elevation" % 10 = 0` and one for `ELSE`, then hide the last ones by simply un-checking the box next to it:

*Uncheck the box next to `ELSE` to hide the white contours:*
[image]